# How to pass the output of scan.nextLine() into another scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a project where I need to scan one line at a time and pass that into another method that does more scanning. currently I have

```
public static void inputStats(Scanner scan)throws FileNotFoundException {
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String text = scan.nextLine();
    printDuplicates(text);// my other method
    }
    }
```

currently java tells me :String cannot be converted to Scanner
my other method simply gets a scanner passed in, the start of it is:
printDuplicates(Scanner scan){
Im not sure how to pass the correct thing, or force it.

alternate solution for me would be having scanner.next stop at the end of a line.

I have tried passing a scanner in by creating a new scanner and passing that in instead of a string.
I have tried forcing the inputs with ().
I have tried every way of not using scanner twice that I know of.

Comment: `printDuplicates(new Scanner(text));` perhaps? What does `printDuplicates` do with the scanner? Why doesn't it just take a `String` instead?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, it worked, apologies for the stupid post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Scanner` that scans a `String` by just passing the string to its [constructor that takes a string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)).

```
printDuplicates(new Scanner(text));
```

Also consider making `printDuplicates` directly take a `String`, and create the scanner inside `printDuplicates`, if it needs to scan tokens.

```
void printDuplicates(String text) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... currently java tells me :String cannot be converted to Scanner ..."*

This is because the *printDuplicates* parameter is a *Scanner* object.

> *"... I have tried passing a scanner in by creating a new scanner and passing that in instead of a string ..."*

This is correct, try it again.

> *"... the start of it is: printDuplicates(Scanner scan){ Im not sure how to pass the correct thing, or force it. ..."*

Either will work, just adjust the *printDuplicates* code.

```java
void printDuplicates(Scanner scan) {
    
    scan.close();
}
```

```java
void printDuplicates(String text) {
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(text)) {
        
    }
}
```